# powershell won't recognize gitlab CI environment variables

Tags: powershell, gitlab-ci

So i am trying to execute a powershell script from my .gitlab-ci.yaml where i want to have one of the script variables based on an environment variable as a starting point for my powershell script.

i have a .gitlab-ci.yaml which includes the following:

```
job1:
  stage: ps
  script:
    - powershell -File .\psfile.ps1 -var1 lalalal -var2 Solution -var3 '%CI_PROJECT_DIR%'
```

when posting the CI_PROJECT_DIR ev from powershell with write-output (or similar) i am getting an empty string.

when i do the common echo '%CI_PROJECT_DIR%' i am getting the correct path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the specifics of GitLab `.gitlab-ci.yaml` files, my guess is that *by default* it is the *host platform's default shell* that is used to execute commands.

**Given that on *Windows* `cmd.exe` is the default shell, you must use *its* syntax**, which implies:

- You need to **use `%...%` to enclose environment-variable references** (which you already do)
- **In order to *quote* a value, you *must* use `"..."` (double quotes)**; by contrast, `'...'` (single quotes) have *no* syntactic function in `cmd.exe` and are passed *as part of the argument*.

Therefore, try with the following line instead:

```
    - powershell -File .\psfile.ps1 -var1 lalalal -var2 Solution -var3 "%CI_PROJECT_DIR%"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$env:CI_PROJECT_DIR` (and remove the single quotes around it in your example because single quotes are literal string constants). This is how environment variables are addressed in PowerShell, the syntax is different to cmd.exe. See also the GitLab documentation [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#using-the-ci-variables-in-your-job-scripts).
If you you want it more detailed in terms of scoping, then you can also call the .net methods `[System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable(...)`

Comment: What you're referring to as scoping is not.  It's accessing the `Env:` drive, just like you would access `Cert:` or `C:` or `HKLM:`.  Scopes are either numbered or named as `local`, `private`, or `global` (I'm sure I'm missing one)

Comment: What interpreter is expanding the `%CI_PROJECT_DIR%` variable reference before PowerShell is started? If it is cmd, then it still needs to  be surrounded with percent characters and not `$Env:`.

Comment: this is highly confusing... I assumed %var% would work when i am kicking off powershell from cmd (havingd %var% as input (prior to being inside ps) ). .... your suggestion of using $env:varname doesn't work. powershell does not recognize the value at all.

Comment: It seems one can put the call to the script in PowerShell syntax directly into the yaml: http://www.powershell.amsterdam/2015/12/04/powershell-and-gitlab-ci-part-3/

Comment: @Tsteenbakkers: That suggests that it is `cmd.exe` that is interpreting your command, in which case the `'` string delimiters are the problem. It would also explain why `$env:CI_PROJECT_DIR` doesn't work, because when you call PowerShell with `-File` (as opposed to `-Command`), the arguments are _not_ expanded.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1: I think bergmeister is referring to the scope of _environment_ variables (`system`, `user`, `process`), not to the scope of _PowerShell_ variables.

Comment: wow... seems like i made a stupid mistake myself. lesson learned by not drinking and coding at the same time. Apparantly i had copied the powershell script and was modifing the old version to show / print the input variable ... needless to say the one i used in Gitlab didnt show any output :\ problem solved. the correct way to use them is indeed "%var%". Thanks all for thinking along :)